# Some gui issues with netbook edition

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, fonts, icons, resize

I don't like the netbook interface released with 10.10, so i want to use the old interface (released with Ubuntu Netbook Edition 10.04). Here how it looks at the moment:

[image]

1. The problem is, that this box is bigger then the others...I've tried to change the font (System -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Fonts), but doesn't work.
2. The icons are pretty big, i have no idea, where i can set the icon size.
3. Maybe the same as the first problem - the font size is to big and i see only part from the name of the program. Setting other font size via Appearance->Fonts doesn't help.

Can someone give me a hint, what must be changed, to fix this problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for the font size problem. I'm using the netbook-launcher-efl, which have two themes: alternative.edj and default.edj, both can be found under `/usr/share/netbook-launcher-efl/data/themes`. I have extracted the default theme with `sudo edje_decc default.edj` under `/usr/share/netbook-launcher-efl/data/themes` and then i've edited the file `default/default.edc`, lines 9,14 and 19 must be changed. I've changed the lines as follow:

- Line 9: font_size=14 was replaced with font_size=10
- Line 14: font_size=12 was replaced with font_size=9
- Line 19: font_size=12 was replaced with font_size=9

Then i build the theme using sudo `sh ./build.sh` and copy the new generated `default.edj` to `/usr/share/netbook-launcher-efl/data/themes`

I still don't have a solution for the icon size, but this isn't now important. Here the new look:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

to change icon size:

1. on the (...)/item you want to change:

   part {

   ```
       name: "e.swallow.icon";
       (...)
       description {
          state: "default" 0.0;
          min: 32 32;
          max: 32 32;
          (...)
       }
       description {
          state: "big" 0.0;
          min: 64 64;
          max: 64 64;
          (...)
      }
    }
   ```
2. in the start of the group, change min:

   group {

   name: "e/netbook/launcher/main/apps/item";

   min: 64 64;
3. play with the parameters min and max until they fit your needs.